# Granting privileges to dbms_crypto

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, security

I'm trying to grant proper privileges for using DBMS_CRYPTO.

Whenever I call it from package it gives me error: 
PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_CRYPTO' must be declared

User already has privileges:
SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE
EXECUTE_CATALOG_ROLE
SELECT ANY DICTIONARY

and EXECUTE on DBMS_CRYPTO to package_owner.

any ideas what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Privileges obtained through a *role* are not in effect inside a stored procedure.

You need to grant the execute privilege explicitely.

Answer (score 11):

This solved the issue for me:

```
grant execute on sys.dbms_crypto to myuser;
```

I had a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13956771/402322) problem with the random function.